# How to send WhatsApp messages using WhatsApp Business Platform created by META in Laravel

Tags: laravel, whatsapp, whatsapi

At first, I need to send messages from my application to users through whatsapp and I found Facebook (META) created WhatsApp Business Platform.I have followed the documentation of the WhatsApp Business Platform  then I have reached this page in the image then,  I need to configure or customize this code with my Laravel project

[last step I have reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBhhV.jpg)